# File Reader not properly reading the blob from a fetch url

Tags: javascript

I want to know why this does not work, it must be a lack of knowledge of how Files and images actually work on javascript, I know this piece of code does not make a lot of sense, there are indeed better ways of writing this code, but in a far point o view of reading the code, it seems to be working code, when it is not.

```
<img id="imageDisplay" alt="Uploaded Image">

<script>
  async function fetchImageAndCreateFile() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://e0.pxfuel.com/wallpapers/696/883/desktop-wallpaper-large-size-and-large-nature.jpg', { mode: 'no-cors' });

    const blob = await response.blob();
    const file = new File([blob], 'image.png', {
      type: 'image/png'
    });

    console.log(file);

    return file;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching image:', error);
  }
}

fetchImageAndCreateFile().then(file => {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('imageDisplay').src = e.target.result;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('Error in main function:', error);
});
</script>
```

I was expecting the image to be displayed on the tag image.

Comment: Remove the mode: 'no-cors' option from your fetch request. However, keep in mind that this will only work if the server allows cross-origin requests.

Comment: Please try copying the code and running on your machine, none of those suggestions worked.

Comment: The most obvious problem would be that you are trying to read a `.jpg` image as an `image/png` file

Comment: @Bergi I tried changing to read as jpg and it still not worked

Comment: `from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`   So why it doesn't work, because CORS is blocking you from doing it, try a site that allows it, eg.  `https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300` and your code will work.

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors'` guarantees you won't have access to the response body even if the site sends CORS headers to allow it - which it doesn't anyway, so the issue is CORS - which is NOT solved on the client - proxy the request using your server